# LINQ to Entities error on ToList with a one-to-many attribute

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Whenever I try to run the following code

```
        employees = from e in this.entities.employees select e;
        var ett = (from e in employees where 
                      (e.salaries.ToList().Where(i => i.to_date.Year == 9999).First().salary1 > TT) 
                  select e);

        var etf = (from e in employees
                  where
                      (e.salaries.ToList().Where(i => i.to_date.Year == 9999).First().salary1 < TT &&
                      e.salaries.ToList().Where(i => i.to_date.Year == 9999).First().salary1 > TF)
                  select e);

        foreach (employee e in ett)
        {
            this.members.memberships.AddObject(new membership
            {
                FirstName = e.first_name,
                LastName = e.last_name,
                MembershipClass = "regular",
                VerificationCode = "abc1234"
            });
        }

        foreach (employee e in etf)
        {
            this.members.memberships.AddObject(new membership
            {
                FirstName = e.first_name,
                LastName = e.last_name,
                MembershipClass = "regular",
                VerificationCode = "abc1234"
            });
        }
```

i get the following error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[app.salary] ToList[salary](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[app.salary])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

The Employee class does maintain a one-to-many relationship to salary. As far as I can read, the errors refer to a .ToList() method call, but removing them has not solved the problem.

EDIT: added more code, hopefully that helps.

Comment: What is `ett` and `etf`? You're not showing the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: the error said `app.salary`, but your code doesn't has the full picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this part: `e.salaries.ToList()` is the problem. You shouldn't have to do `.ToList()` to do linq query, try without the `.ToList()`

```
var ett = (from e in employees where 
                      (e.salaries.Where(i => i.to_date.Year == 9999).First().salary1 > TT) 
                  select e);

    var etf = (from e in employees
              where
                  (e.salaries.Where(i => i.to_date.Year == 9999).First().salary1 < TT &&
                  e.salaries.Where(i => i.to_date.Year == 9999).First().salary1 > TF)
              select e);
```